# I don't know if it is safe to update genetic kernel to 4.8

Tags: kernel

Is it safe to update Os Loki, to the newest 4.8 kernel?
I now have 4.4-generic kernel.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Now that the Ubuntu 16.04.2 was released, you can safely update to the 4.8 kernel version. It's safe and works without issues. You can use this command:

`sudo apt-get install --install-recommends xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04`

Comment: so if it safe, why doesn't elemntary os give you the option to upgrade via AppCenter?

Answer (score 4):

It is relatively safe, though problems can always manifest. I recommend using Ukuu to do the upgrade and follow the method listed here:

http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/upgrade-kernel-ukuu-ubuntu/

This allows you to easily roll back to 4.4 if you are experiencing issues.